# Why do transistors emit photons when switching?

Tags: photons, semiconductor-physics

I was reading up on this topic about [photon emission of ICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-resolved_photon_emission) and I stumbled over the sentence

> As pMOS and nMOS transistors switch on or off, they emit photons.

Why?

Comment: Any time an electron (bound) changes orbitals, it either absorbs or emits a photon.  In the absence of more details (perhaps found in references on that wiki page), I would guess that the switching process  leads to  free electrons being bound to receptor atoms.

Comment: Carrier recombination leads to photon emission, even in silicon (it just isn't particularly efficient and is not in the visible). So, think of how an MOS device works, and how the carrier concentrations needed for on/off are instantiated and then dissipate.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you! I never heard throughout my study that recombination leads to photon emission. I'm quite surprised. So a MOS typically emits a lot of photons? When I google this topic I only receive rather specialized search results, do you know a "general" source I can read up?